# VBA CountIFs not returning values expected

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, countif

Here is my code:

```
      Dim CurrMonth As String
     Dim PosMatch As Variant
     Dim MonthDayCount As Variant
     Dim MonthDays As Variant
     Dim C285 As Variant
     Dim EntryDates As Range
     Dim EntrySheet As Range
     Dim LastRow As Integer
     Dim Ident As Variant
     Dim p As Integer
     Dim x As Integer
     
     CurrMonth = Format$(Date, "MMMM")
     
     With Worksheets("Entry Log")
     LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     
     Set EntryDates = .Range("A3" & ":A" & LastRow)
     Set EntrySheet = .Range("B3" & ":B" & LastRow)
     
     With Worksheets("Tracker")
     PosMatch = Application.Match(CurrMonth, .Range("A:A"), 0)

     MonthDayCount = .Cells(PosMatch, "A").End(xlToRight).Column - 1
     
     MonthDays = Application.Index(.Range(.Cells(PosMatch, 2), .Cells(PosMatch, MonthDayCount + 1)).Value, 1, 0)
     
     ReDim C285(1 To MonthDayCount)
     
     For p = 1 To 4
     Ident = .Range("A" & PosMatch).Offset(p, 0)
     
     For x = 1 To MonthDayCount
     
     C285(x) = Application.CountIfs(EntrySheet, Ident, EntryDates, MonthDays(x))
     
     If x = MonthDayCount Then
     .Range(.Cells(PosMatch + p, 2), .Cells(PosMatch + p, MonthDayCount + 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(C285)
     End If
     
    Next x
    Next p
    End With
    End With
End Sub
```

This code takes information from 2 places, one of those being a calendar with all the months laid out and the other a column with a list of dates and worksheet names.

As per above, `EntryDates` is a column of dates and `EntrySheet` is a column filled with worksheet names.

`MonthDays` is a list of dates for that month that is dynamic based on the month it is, currently it contains all the days for June in dd/mm/yyyy format output as string.

`Ident` is the name of the sheet that will match with the names in the  `EntrySheet` column of data.

With all that, `C285` array still returns only 0's. I have tried a normal CountIfs formula inputting the same data manually and it works perfectly, however I can't get a correct answer out of this and I'm not sure as to why (output is identical if I don't loop through the `C285` array For x)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you writing over the information when you get to p=4?  It looks like you're writing over the same array 4 times.

Comment: `C285(x) = Application.CountIfs(EntrySheet, Ident, EntryDates, MonthDays(x))` may either need to become multi-dimensional, or you need to add the older values to the newer values, e.g., `C285(x) = C285(x) + Application.CountIfs(EntrySheet, Ident, EntryDates, MonthDays(x))`

Comment: @Cyril I'm observing the first loop only, I will be adding a transpose when it reaches MonthDayCount, the p loop then will move up and another value will be set for Ident which should change the properties of the CountIfs to count a different set of values from the same range. At least, that's what it should do.

Comment: Please include your actual code, including your transposing of data.  I can only assume is between the lines `next x` and `next p`, but that positioning may be part of the issue for why you're seeing zeroes.  I see no checks, e.g., `debug.print c285(x)`, in the provided code where you are observing the first loop.

Comment: For clarity sake, also adjust your `With` statements... currently they are nested for what appears to be no significant reason, so ending one with before moving to the next with would definitely help.

Comment: @Cyril I added the transpose that works to output C285 for P = 1 and then moves down to output the next C285 as it is over-written for P = 2 until P = 4. But still, unfortunately with 0's as CountIfs don't seem to work.